# Shorthand syntax for U-Boot arguments

Tags: linux, quoting, embedded, u-boot

What is proper syntax for setenv bootargs command when using shorthand syntax for method? For example, the full kernel environment variables is

```
U-Boot> setenv bootargs console=ttyS1,115200n8 rootfstype=squashfs noalign half_image=0 verify=y Hw_Model=pnx8181 Router_Mode=0
```

I want to add 2 bootargs to the mentioned code,`single` and `init=/bin/sh`.

Is the following command with shorthand syntax correct?

`setenv bootargs ${bootargs} single init=/bin/sh`

No single quotes are required anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that syntax should work fine. If you're in doubt, you can double check by running `printenv bootargs`. By the way, you can also run `editenv bootargs` which will let you arrow over wherever you want and edit the variable easily. If you're trying to make your change persistent, you need to run `saveenv` to keep the changes for the next reboot.

Comment: How to remove bootargs when it's not required?

Comment: You can remove variables with the `env` command. I believe the syntax is `env del bootargs`, but I don't have a PC in front of me to check. You could also just run `setenv bootargs ""` to set bootargs to an empty string. With both of these, you will need to run `saveenv` to keep your changes persistent.